# Buffer works for signal from function generator, but not guitar signal

Tags: buffer

I am trying to create a buffer for a project I am working on. I found this schematic on line and built it. When I input a guitar signal the output equals V+ rather than giving the signal at the opposite side. It works as expected with a signal from a function generator. How can I fix this and why is it happening? I am using a TL074 rather than a TL071. I have configured the pins with 4 to V+ and 11 to ground.

[image]

Comment: Hard to say with the given info. What is the supply voltage and where does it come from? Is it built correctly?

Comment: Have you properly tied off the unused op-amps in the quad?

Comment: I'm guessing (of course) that your guitar uses one of [these kinds of pickups](https://www.sweetwater.com/insync/how-do-guitar-pickups-work/). Regardless, though, it is pretty important to know exactly what kind of pickup is involved. You can see a pickup in [this picture of the same guitar I have -- a 1953 ES-140 Gibson](https://www.creamcitymusic.com/1953-gibson-es-140-3-4-hollow-body-electric-guitar-sunburst-finish/), [zoomed up here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYKBy.png). These are magnetic reluctance devices. They aren't the same thing as a signal generator.

Comment: Add a resistor (eg. 10kΩ) to ground and measure the output voltage again. Leakage in the electrolytic capacitor will cause it to read about V+/2 with a high-Z meter. If it's actually reading V+ then you probably have a short or a missing ground connection.